# SwiftyJson: Looping an array inside an array

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swifty-json

I am trying to loop through an array inside an array. The first loop was easy but I'm having trouble looping through the second array inside it. Any suggestions would be welcome!

```
{
"feeds": [
{
  "id": 4,
  "username": "andre gomes",
  "feeds": [
    {
      "message": "I am user 4",
      "like_count": 0,
      "comment_count": 0
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 5,
  "username": "renato sanchez",
  "feeds": [
    {
      "message": "I am user 5",
      "like_count": 0,
      "comment_count": 0
    },
    {
      "message": "I am user 5-2",
      "like_count": 0,
      "comment_count": 0
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

As you see I'm having trouble to reach through to the message field etc

Here's my code on swiftyjson

```
let json = JSON(data: data!)

for item in json["feeds"].arrayValue {

print(item["id"].stringValue)
print(item["username"].stringValue)
print(item["feeds"][0]["message"])
print(item["feeds"][0]["like_count"])
print(item["feeds"][0]["comment_count"])

}
```

The output I get is

```
4
andre gomes
I am user 4
0
0
5
renato sanchez
I am user 5
0
0
```

As you see I'm unable to get the message"I am user 5-2" and corresponding like_count and comment_count

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already demonstrated how to loop through a JSON array so you only need to do it again with the inner `feeds`:

```
let json = JSON(data: data!)

for item in json["feeds"].arrayValue {

    print(item["id"].stringValue)
    print(item["username"].stringValue)

    for innerItem in item["feeds"].arrayValue {
        print(innerItem["message"])
        print(innerItem["like_count"])
        print(innerItem["comment_count"])
    }

}
```

If you only want the first item in the inner `feeds` array, replace the inner for lop with this:

```
print(item["feeds"].arrayValue[0]["message"])
print(item["feeds"].arrayValue[0]["like_count"])
print(item["feeds"].arrayValue[0]["comment_count"])
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! The two feeds array sure did confuse me at first but your answer cleared things up!

Comment: Is there anyway I can print the id and username inside the inner item loop? The thing is it will ease up storage when there are multiple inner feeds

Comment: Just move the `print(item["id"].stringValue)` line into the inner loop